# Alternate phrase for exciting opportunity?

Tags: phrases

Any thoughts on an alternate phrase for "exciting opportunity"? It's such an overused phrase. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the context, one of these should fit:

1. **once-in-a-lifetime opportunity**
2. **big break**
3. **chance of a lifetime**

> break: an opportunity that helps you to be successful  (Macmillan English Dictionary)

Answer (score 2):

How about "dull job that doesn't pay very well, provide health benefits, or paid vacation"?

That description is not overused.

Comment: Ha! Yes - a common use for the phrase when covering up details in job descriptions. I, however,am just wondering from an editing standpoint. Many of the docs I have to edit about technology use that phrase.

Comment: Does it involve an investment opportunity?

Comment: No. Just advancements in the travel technology space offering "exciting opportunities" to property managers of vacation rentals. I know - super sexy topic.

Comment: I'd succinctly describe a core feature and let those who would be excited by it get excited.    *Travel to anywhere and to anytime in the known Universe (some restrictions may apply).*